# R ggplot linear regression model containing log function

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, log-analysis

R ggplot linear regression model containing log function - is this valid, are we allowed to perform linear regression on model whereby both dependent and independent variable contains log terms.

Example:

```
mdl1 <- lm(log(abs(y)) ~ log(abs(x1)) + log(abs(x2)) + x3 + x4, data)

predicted_mdl1 <- data %>%
  data_grid(x1, # parameter to check the effect on the model
            x2=1, #log term set to 1 to make it zero
            x3, # categorical variable
            x4) %>%
  add_predictions(mdl1)

predicted_mdl1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = log(x1), y = pred, color = factor(x3))
  )
```

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What additional packages are you using besides `ggplot2` here? What exactly is your question?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to fit in a linear regression line to show relationship between x and y variable, wondering whether its is a valid expectation to fit a linear regression line for variable containing log terms. 

Packages used: modelr, ggplot2

Comment: Who determines what's "valid"? Is this a statistical question? If so, then you should ask at [stats.se] instead. I don't see a specific programming question here that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.